# Show different logo based on URL

Tags: magento2, varnish

I want to show a different logo if a user is redirected from a specific site. This logo should show the reset of the session. The problem I'm facing is that we're using Varnish, and the logo shows up to other users (that are not redirected from the specific site).

How can I show this logo (with Varnish in mind) based on the URL, for example: https://domain.com?ref=1

I tried different solutions:

- With Cookie (Cookie is not always set and we still have the problem with Varnish)
- Added a Http Vary

Answer (score 0):

you should try with javascript, you could save the referer in registry and add a json object into a phtml with url and logo info, then you could ask for registry saved referer to a custom controller

```
Mage::register('name-of-registry-key', $your-data);
$var = Mage::registry('name-of-registry-key');
```

Comment: Hi, have you been able to fix the issue? If this answer have been in help could you mark it as the accepted answer?